# Regex to allow mathmetical operation

Tags: python, regex, django

This is the regex that I currently have (which doesn't work)

```
^(pow|sqrt|[0-9*,/\-\+\(\)])+$
```

What I want is to ONLY allow the following characters: `+` `-` `/` `,` `*` `(` `)`, numbers `0-9` and these words `pow` `sqrt`.
Its basically to allow only basic maths operation and `pow(x,x)` and `sqrt(x)` where x is a number.

Example:

> 2+2 should pass
>
> pow(3,2) should pass
>
> abs(3.33) should fail 3*2+3 -(10/2) should pass

Comment: What are you trying to do? Allow these regexs where? Are you taking input from the user?

Comment: _this doesn't work_ should include an example..

Comment: @MiteshNinja Yes. I basically get this from user input and I want to validate them before I do eval on them

Comment: mark my word..regex is not the best way to do this task..you will make one regex and there will be 10 exceptions for that..either specify all the set of inputs that are allowed

Comment: @DesterDezzods You really don't want to use regex for something like this. Evaluting user input should be highly 'DETERMINISTIC' or restricted.

Comment: @MiteshNinja what would be the better solution according to u?

Comment: @DesterDezzods check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted two errors, you should escape `/` as well, and you forgot the number `0`. But this may differ over different regex implementations.

```
^(pow|sqrt|[0-9*,\/\-\+\(\)])+$
```

Of course, this regex in no way ensures that the sentence is a valid math operation, for example: `powpow12/*-12` will be accepted. Regex is not a suitable tool to parse mathematical expressions.

https://regex101.com/r/cI6oM2/1

Comment: this will accept `powpowpowpow` which is totally invalid..i know that's OP concern but I don't think this is complete solution

Comment: @rock321987 Yes, there are 3 million sentences that will be accepted that are not valid math operations. You need a parser to check that.

Comment: Exactly. I've provided links in my answer to a very simple calculator parser in pure python which should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not directly answer OP's problem. I feel that these are a required reading, specially when dealing with USER input.

> - SANDBOX ESCAPE
>     This is the traditional rationale against using eval(). You cannot simply let the user to run arbitrary code on the server, as they could simply do import os ; os.remove(“/home”).
> - CPU BURNING ATTACK
>     If you let the user to input arbitrary calculations, they can try to make the calculations so complex that your process keeps calculating the math expression forever, mounting a denial of service attack against the service.
> - MEMORY BURNING ATTACK
>     Memory burning attack is similar to CPU burning attack. Instead of CPU cycles, the attacker tries to run make the process run out of memory. One could input a very long math expression. Alternatively, the power operation could be used to create very large numbers not fitting to the process memory.

Read more here: https://opensourcehacker.com/2014/10/29/safe-evaluation-of-math-expressions-in-pure-python/

---

To provide eval-like safish method for user interaction, there are two libraries which I could find:

- http://newville.github.io/asteval/index.html
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython

But these can be rather heavy and complex. So, apart from these, you can also write a **simple parser** using `PLY` and feed the input to the parser. Here is a *complete example* of making a calcuator using PLY: https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/master/example/calc/calc.py

Since `PLY` is pure python. This should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues :

```
^(pow|sqrt|[0-9\*\,/\-\+\(\)])+$
```

should works.
But it doesn't take care of character order, "pow9(10,sqrt" will be correct and you can't do this with regex.